# SSH works, SFTP doesnt

Tags: ssh, sftp

I've got a file with SSH private key. When I try to access server
with command

```
ssh -vvv -i key *@*.*.*.* -p2222
```

, it validates the key -

```
debug1: Trying private key: key
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: ED25519 SHA256:9Lxb74WbUExNBifvtYtUuqI4gebuim0hg024jSqlvDo
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 52
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
```

After that the connection fails, saying "This service allows sftp connections only.".

But when I try to connect through sftp with the same key

```
sftp -vvv -i key *@*.*.*.* -p2222
```

, the key is not verified anymore.

```
debug1: Trying private key: key
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: ED25519 SHA256:9Lxb74WbUExNBifvtYtUuqI4gebuim0hg024jSqlvDo
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
```

Can you please help me finding the problem?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the actual ssh and sftp commands that you're running, and include any relevant parts of your .ssh/config file.

Comment: Thanks, I edited and added the commands I used. In my .ssh/config there is nothing related to the problem.

Comment: Is SFTP enabled on the server? It is a separate service provided by sshd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sftp -vvv -i key *@*.*.*.* -p2222
```

The problem is your `-p2222` option. There are two issues:

1. The OpenSSH `sftp` command uses `-p` for a different purpose than `ssh`. To specify the remote SSH port for sftp, use the `-P` (capital P) option.
2. The OpenSSH `sftp` command doesn't accept -P (or -p) at that position in the command line. You need to move the option to come before the user@host argument.

In short, try this:

```
sftp -vvv -i key -P2222 *@*.*.*.*
```